# html, draggable menu freez in android chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried to make a drag-and-drop menu for mobile browsers [(it's here)](https://jsfiddle.net/946qfras/), checked it in firefox and it works fine, but for some reason in Chrome it freezes what I'm doing wrong and if possible, how to fix it

js:

```
dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;

    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").addEventListener("touchstart", dragMouseDown, false);
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").addEventListener("touchmove", elementDrag, false);

  function dragMouseDown(e) {

    pos3 = e["changedTouches"][0].clientX;
    pos4 = e["changedTouches"][0].clientY;

  }

  function elementDrag(e) {

    pos1 = pos3 - e["changedTouches"][0].clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e["changedTouches"][0].clientY;
    pos3 = e["changedTouches"][0].clientX;
    pos4 = e["changedTouches"][0].clientY;

    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

}
```

thanks in advance,
and sorry for this english

Comment: Seems to be ok on iPad IOS in both Chrome and Safari. What version Chrome do you have on Android?

Comment: chrome 85.0.4183.127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add to css:

```
touch-action: none;
user-select: none;
```

... but how ? (ಥ _ ಥ)